# Pass hidden fields using drupalSettings to Twig template

Tags: 8, hooks, paragraphs

We have a paragraph field (`field_pr_custom`) on the `Basic` page content type that has a custom twig template, `pr-custom.html.twig`. In the twig template, we need to pass in an array inside of a `<script>` tag. To accomplish this, we use the `mymodule_preprocess_paragraph__pr_custom` hook and set the array using the `#attached` variable. However, when we print the `drupalSettings` we are not finding the value passed in. There is no `Drupal behavior` used.

**How can we pass the value in an array from the `mymodule_preprocess_paragraph__pr_custom` into the `drupalSettings` variable inside the `pr-custom.html.twig` template?**

Here is what we tried:

**mymodule.module**

```
function mymodule_preprocess_paragraph__pr_custom(&$variables) {
  // pass node id.
  $node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node');
  if($node instanceof \Drupal\node\NodeInterface) {
    $variables['elements']['#attached']['drupalSettings']['myArray']['myvar'] = $node->id();
  }
}
```

**pr-custom.html.twig**

```
<div>
  {{ content.field_text }}
  <script>
    // this doesn't print myArray and doesn't even have it. 
    console.log(drupalSettings); 
  </script>
</div>
```

Comment: 1) In this hook you can only add the node id of the parent entity to drupalSettings, not a route parameter. For this use a more global hook like `hook_page_attachments`. 2) Inline javascript is not recommended, put the javascript in a library, see https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/272731/47547

Comment: @4k4 moving it to the `hook_page_attachments` did the job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wish I could comment...

Are you sure your hook is running?  the `instanceof` operator is not implemented correctly so you should be seeing an error when the hook tries to run.

Also, you may not need to add 'drupalSettings' to the 'elements' key.  You should be able to put it on the top level of $variables.

Comment: the `instance of` was a typo and has been corrected on the question. Putting it in the top level or `parent entity` as mentioned by @4k4 did the job.

Comment: $variables['#attached']['drupalSettings']['blah']... works.